# Unity3D failed at launching on Mac

Tags: unity-game-engine

While trying to launch Unity3d (4.6.1) on Mac(10.10) it gives a popup with this message: Opening file /tmp/licenseloader.html failed because the file or directory doesn't exist.
Please Help.[image]

Comment: This close vote is wrong - this directly relates to a programming tool.

Comment: Sounds like missing files - tried reinstalling?

Comment: yes i tried to re-install several times. i even tried some old versions. :(

Answer (score 1):

found the solution finally. have to run Unity as sudo:

```
sudo /Applications/Unity/Unity.app/Contents/MacOS/Unity
```

Comment: I ran this as sudo, then quit and re-ran as normal. Problem fixed. Bizarre.